# Regex : match a string containing only one alphabet

Tags: python, regex

If there is a string

str= "S23#"

It should match and

if str="WS23%"

it should not match (because 2 characters)

I used  `re.search("^[{A-Z}?0-9()*%#+?=:._<>,!/\-]*$", str)` and it matches both strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the pattern which matches all the uppercase alphabets from the character class and put it in between two `[0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*` patterns.

```
re.match(r"^[0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*[A-Za-z][0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*$", st)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s= "S23#"
>>> s1 = "WS23%"
>>> re.match(r"^[0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*[A-Za-z][0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*$", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='S23#'>
>>> re.match(r"^[0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*[A-Za-z][0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]*$", s1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!(.*?[A-Z]){2})[{A-Z}?0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]+$
```

Try this.Also use `re.match` if you want to match the whole string.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/2

`re.match("^(?!(.*?[A-Z]){2})[{A-Z}?0-9()%#+?=:._<>,!/-]+$", str)`